# jQuery make variable out of links used in plugin

Tags: jquery, variables, initialization, href, soundcloud

This is a weird one, I apologize.

I'm working with Soundcloud's [Custom Player](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/wiki/) and need to make a variable out of the src of each link the plugin is initiated on. I've been digging around the source and can't find where it takes the links in and starts manipulating them. [Here is the source>](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js)

So to be clear, there are a bunch of links on my page:

```
<a class="sc" href="link/to/soundcloud/">yeah!</a>
```

The plugin is initialized with:

```
$('a.sc').scPlayer();
```

I'd like to make a variable out of each of the links `.attr('href');` for use in a special little GUI piece that I'm adding within the guts of the plugin. Essentially, I'm building a URL to make a pop-out window and need to give each instance of the `$player` it's own link that will correspond to a subfolder on the site.

Unfortunately, this one is just digging around the source and a lot of the techniques/methods involved are just over my head. For what it's worth, I did try this myself for a good long while before I  decided to ask here. You'll find on line `134` that the player's source is set. This is in the HTML5 driver instead of the Flash one.. so It's not quite ideal but on the right track.

Where on earth is each links `href` brought in and manipulated? Driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand it correctly, but for me it seems that the tracks are processed on the line 523 within the `$.each` function.
It looks like there is the object - `track` that has a member named `permalink_url` that holds the URI.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but those are the tracks from the playlist. So for example, I'm building several players, each with soundcloud links that link to a set. What I'd like to do is grab that link within the plugin. By the time that each() function is processed, it's visited that url and grabbed all the tracks from the set. see the difference?

Comment: I'm sorry but I guess I dont understand how that plugin works so I still dont know what are you trying to achieve :)

Comment: Tell me about it. It's a weird one.